# Routing change from Rails 2 to Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I had this route in my Rails 2.x app

```
map.with_options(:controller => "web_page") do |site|
    site.connect "*url", :action => "index"
end
```

which directed every namespace after my root to a controller called 'web_page' and to an action called 'index'

For example, if a I type http://localhost:3000/products it goes to http://localhost:3000/web_pages/index

If I type http://localhost:3000/services still it goes to http://localhost:3000/web_pages/index

But how can I do this in Rails 3 routes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
match '/:all' => 'web_page#index', :constraints => { :all => /.+/ }
```

request to http://example.com/this/is/a/test?option=true become:

```
class WebPageController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @all = params[:all] # "this/is/a/test"
    @path = request.path # "/this/is/a/test"
    @query = request.query_parameters # {"option"=>"true"} 
  end
end
```